# Will every IoT device will have their own wallet, own seed?

Tags: seed, legacy-protocol, internet-of-things, exchanges

Will every *IoT device* will have their *own wallet with their own seed*, or how is this planned?

What if every IoT device will have their own seed and so we run out of seeds? 
Is this possible?

What if I accidentally generate a seed that's already used? Or is this chance that 81 characters are the same to small?

Have exchanges like Bitfinex one seed for IOTA and safe their IOTAS their or do they have one seed for every user, who has got IOTAs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy protocol and given the latest updates it might make sense to only keep recent Shimmer, ShimmerEVM and IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Will every IOT Device have its own seed?

I recommend you take a look at [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/268/multi-seeds-or-multi-addresses-for-sensors/272#272) that was already asked before.

## Will we ever run out of seeds?

No. There are so many possible seeds that this will never be an issue. The number of possible seeds is unimaginably high. A human brain has difficulties when dealing with big numbers and that's why you are worried about it but there are basically close to infinite (not really but **our brains don't even know the difference between 8.7×10¹¹⁵ and infinity**) possible seeds.

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions in there. However I think they're are connected enough to handle them as one SE question.

> Will every IoT device will have their own wallet with their own seed,
>   or how is this planned?

That's not feasible since not every device has the ability to calculate hashes or to store a seed securely. Devices that can do both can use their own wallets.

> What if every IoT device will have their own seed and so we run out of
>   seeds? Is this possible?

The number is too big. 27<sup>81</sup> to be precise. There won't be a shortage of seeds.

> What if I accidentally generate a seed that's already used?

**That would be bad.**

> Or is this chance that 81 characters are the same to small?

It would be pretty slim if everyone generated seeds randomly. People will be stupid and be using ABCDEF... seeds.

Comment: There is no password attached to your seed. i.e. same seed = same account. If you generate a seed already use by another user you will have access to all his iota's.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the first part of your question but that somebody generates the same seed as somebody else is nearly impossible.

Compared to the universe, there are approximately 10<sup>81</sup> particles existing and there are approximately 8×10<sup>115</sup> seed combinations.

[image]

[Original](https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/6wxdp6/odds_of_getting_the_same_seed/)

Comment: but when every IoT device will have a own seed, this huge number will gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: Yes that is true but it's like the number 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 is smaller than 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000. still pretty big

Comment: Even if there are trillions of used seeds the number of seeds you have to check is so huge it would take a long time.

Comment: You forgot to obfuscate your chrome user...

Comment: @Helmar It's not me the owner is linked under the picture :)

Comment: Not sure sharing someone else's is better...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://matthewwinstonjohnson.gitbooks.io/iota-guide-and-faq/how-secure-is-my-seed.html) you´ll find a very concrete and impressively done exemplification of how numerous the possible combinations are.

> Now let's say you have a super computer composed of the entirety of the matter in our solar system, and powered by 100% of our sun, letting you (somehow) generate and read every address associated with 1 trillion different seeds per second.
>   8.7x10^115 seeds / 1x10^12 generated per second = 8.7x10^103 seconds = 2.8x10^96 years to process all IOTA seeds.

Comment: That doesn't even try to answer the titular question.